# Non-Traditional Bayesian Nash Equilibrium in a Duopoly Cournot Competition

Tags: game-theory, bayesian, nash-equilibrium

I am having a hard time to solve a Bayesian Nash equilibrium game in a duopoly cournot competition setting. So, I have two firms with **given** production quantities, let's say $q_1$ and $q_2$ (i.e., not a decision). Firm 1's product is low quality whereas Firm 2's product is high quality with probability $\theta$ and low quality with $1-\theta$. As a result, different quality products have different market potential for Firm 2. The way I set up the price function for low quality is
$$M-q_1-q_2$$
For high quality products, there is a price premium such that the price for high quality is given by $$\alpha M-q_1-q_2$$ where $\alpha>1$. Another different aspect of the problem is that companies first sell products in the primary market under the price mechanism specified above. There exist a secondary market. It works in a way such that if any firm sells his (remaining) products there, he gets a guaranteed price $m$ (M > m).
Currently my solution involves 8 different cases. I solve Bayesian Nash equilibrium by solving three profit functions simultaneously to find the quantities to supply in the primary market. Since $q_1$ and $q_2$ are treated fixed, I need to have a $\min \{q_i, \hat{q}_i\}$ for $i=1, 2H, 2L$, where $\hat{q}_i$ is the equilibrium solution for the primary market. But I am trying to narrow the cases down to a small set so that I can continue my other analysis with the solution. Accordingly, I have two questions: **1. Is my current solution correct? 2. How can I narrow cases down to a manageable number?**

If you wonder what my equilibrium solution looks like for primary market, here it is.
$$\hat{q}_1 =\frac{M-m}{3}-\frac{\theta (\alpha M-M)}{3}$$
$$\hat{q}_{2L} =\frac{M-m}{3}+\frac{\theta (\alpha M-M)}{6}$$
$$\hat{q}_{2H}^M = \frac{\alpha M-m}{3}+\frac{(1+\theta)(\alpha M-M)}{6}$$